# How can I make the icons larger and/or clearer in Classic Menu Indicator?

Tags: 12.04, unity, indicator, appmenu, panel

I use the classic menu indicator and I've noticed that the icons are small and blurry. At first I thought that it was the icon theme that just didn't have icons at that size, so I tried various other themes and they were all blurry too. Is it possible to go into Dconf-Editor or something like that to set the icon size to something larger? Thanks

[image: The icons are blurry]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Making the icons clearer

The option that *should* makes icons larger doesn't work, probably because it's constrained by the overall Ubuntu font size setting, but here's how to make the icons **less blurry** (clearer).

- In `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py`, find this at or around line 97:

  `pixbuf.scale_simple(width, self.icon_size, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)`
- and change the last part to:

  `pixbuf.scale_simple(width, self.icon_size, gtk.gdk.INTERP_HYPER)`
- This uses a better algorithm for scaling to the icons to the smaller size, and they look better -- compare before (left) and after (right), at 500% magnification:

  [image]